# Parse JSON with list of single string element by RestKit

Tags: ios, json, rest, restkit

How can I configure RestKit for parsing this JSON:

```
{"platform":["This field is required."],"push_token":["This field is required."]}
```

Can the RestKit support different various sets of field in this JSON? With only one field "platform" or one field "push_token" or both fields as shown in example.

**UPD:**

```
@interface Register : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * platform;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * push_token;

+ (void) initEntityForRestKit;
+ (NSString *) getURL;
+ (NSDictionary*) elementToPropertyMappings;
+ (RKObjectMapping *) entityMapping;

@end

@implementation Register

+ (NSString *) getURL {
    return @"/api/register/";
}

+ (void) initEntityForRestKit {
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseFaultDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor
                                                     responseDescriptorWithMapping:[Register entityMapping]
                                                     pathPattern:[Register getURL]
                                                     keyPath:nil
                                                     statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseFaultDescriptor];
}

+ (NSDictionary*)elementToPropertyMappings {
    return @{@"platform":@"platform",
             @"push_token":@"push_token"};
}

+ (RKObjectMapping *) entityMapping {
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Register class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[Register elementToPropertyMappings]];

    return mapping;
}

@end
```

**UPD2:**

```
2015-09-30 17:22:18.756 test[50727:2976562] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:215 POST 'http://test.com/api/register/' (400 Bad Request / 0 objects) [request=0.2629s mapping=0.0000s total=0.4324s]: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Loaded an unprocessable error response (400)" UserInfo=0x7fad39651530 {NSLocalizedDescription=Loaded an unprocessable error response (400), NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://test.com/api/register/}
2015-09-30 17:22:18.756 test[50727:2976487] E app:AppDelegate.m:89 Load failed with error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Loaded an unprocessable error response (400)" UserInfo=0x7fad39651530 {NSLocalizedDescription=Loaded an unprocessable error response (400), NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://test.com/api/register/}
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking, show the class definition you're trying to map into.

Comment: @Wain , done. But this code don't work :)

Comment: confused here, do you mean that above code can't parse the json you mentioned above? or you are just asking whether above code works for your purpose?

Comment: @ybbaigo That code doesnt work with json wich is presented above

Comment: What's the error info from restkit?

Comment: @ybbaigo Error info In "UPD2"

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the source code of `Restkit`. If it's an error response, it will always return an error. You can debug into below code for your situation.

```
// If the response is a client error return either the mapping error or the mapped result to the caller as the error
if (isErrorStatusCode) {
    if ([self.mappingResult count] > 0) {
        error = RKErrorFromMappingResult(self.mappingResult);
    } else {
        // We encountered a client error that we could not map, throw unprocessable error
        if (! error) error = RKUnprocessableErrorFromResponse(self.response);
    }
    self.error = error;
    [self willFinish];
    return;
}
```

You can find the code here https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Code/Network/RKResponseMapperOperation.m#L378